# Combine depth images from two cameras using the world matrix

Tags: rendering, camera, geometry

In my simple scene I have a very simple model and two cameras. From each camera I know the external parameters *Pi* (from `bpy.data.objects['Cam0'].matrix_world`) and both have the same internal parameters *K*. Additionally, I have one rendered depthmap (z-buffer) per camera.

From the depthmap I should be able to generate a point cloud *X*, with *Xi = Pi^-1 xi*, where x are the pixel scaled with its depth. However, if I combine the point clouds, they do not match, because they one is rotated away from the other.

Is *P* the used projection matrix (excluding *K*), especially is the rotation of the camera correct in terms of what I want to achieve?

EDIT:
I have uploaded a example that illustrates my problem. From the setting in the blend file I have generated two depthmaps (are both contained as exr and as ascii txt). Further, the Matlab example visualizes the rotation errror. [Example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3115518/blend/multiview.tar.gz)

Comment: If the point clouds rotate apart than the transformation is wrong, when Xi are in world coordinates what is the rotation center? Perhaps you could add a .blend containing your cameras and the point clouds. From my understanding Pi would transform say a cube at the origin to the position and orientation of the camera Pi^-1  would apply the inverse transformation.

Comment: See also this paper http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-12232009-222118/unrestricted/Short_NJ_T_2009.pdf page 13pp.

Comment: I have uploaded an example.

Comment: You are doing all the calculations in mathlab , I couldn't convert the ascii files with meshlab (meshlab.sourceforge.net) for use in blender. I would have give it a try if I could do it in blender instead of mathlab (I don't have). Now the question seems to be off-topic.

Comment: The problem can also be visualized (with the same scripts) with Octave, which is open source.